# Show product attribute in Woocommerce below product title

Tags: woocommerce, attributes

I have found some code here on the site, to show a product attribute on the category pages. This works fine, it shows the attribute I want perfectly, but it would be really perfect if I could get this just below th product title, and not below the button, as where it is now. Can someone help me how I can do this?

[this is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82Io.jpg)

```
 /**
 * PPM
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'acf_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );
function acf_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    // Check that we got the instance of the WC_Product object, to be sure (can be removed)
    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    echo '<h4>Afdruksnelheid: ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_afdruksnelheid') .' PPM</h4>';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_before_title' );
function custom_before_title() {

global $product;

    // Check that we got the instance of the WC_Product object, to be sure (can be removed)
    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    echo '<h4>Afdruksnelheid: ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_afdruksnelheid') .' PPM</h4>';


}
```

There is no hook exactly in the place you mentioned. Check this [hook guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) for more info

Comment: Thank you for the solution and info Mujeebu Rahman, that's close enough to what I wanted!

Comment: I have one more question about this, maybe you can help me also. Now this displays on every category, even on category's that have nothing to do with this attribute. Is there a way to exclude certain category pages from showing this?

Comment: Check like is_category( 'test-ing' ); // it will check for is it a category page and the slug is test-ing